# How is shellcode generated from C? - With code example

Tags: python, c, gcc, assembly, shellcode

I started taking an online course regarding software security. In one of the sections, I was instructed to execute a hidden C function using a buffer overflow. I got to thinking: what would happen if I could pass machine instruction directly to a stack unsafe executable?

What I have been trying, or where I am at now:

```
(Simple routine or function compiled or assembled into an object, 
then printed to screen with `objdump`)

>>> x = "984579273698529424576299" # open("file.o").read()
>>> for i in range(0, len(x), 2):
...     print "\\x" + x[i:i+2],
...
\x98 \x45 \x79 \x27 \x36 \x98 \x52 \x94 \x24 \x57 \x62 \x99

int main(void) {
    unsigned char shellcode[] = { <formatted shellcode bytes from objdump> };
    void (*fn)(void) = (void (*)(void))shellcode;
    fn();
    return 0;
}
```

An **actual** example of some sequences I've tried:

**hello.c**

```
int main(void) 
{
    char buf[] = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\n', '\0'};
    write(1, buf, sizeof(buf));
    exit(0);
}
```

**shellforge2.py** (a work in progress)

```
import os
import re
import sys

src = sys.argv[1]
asmsrc = src[:src.find(".")] + ".s"
binobj = src[:src.find(".")] + ".o"
call = "gcc -march=i386 -O3 -S -fPIC -Winline " + \
        "-finline-functions  -ffreestanding " + \
        "-o %s -m32 %s" % (asmsrc, src)
print call
print
f = os.popen(call)
f.close()

asm = open(asmsrc).readlines()
ignores = (".file", ".def")
asm_stripped = []
for line in asm:
    write = True
    for ignore in ignores:
        if ignore in line: write = False
    if write: print line.replace("\n", "")

ret = os.system("gcc -c -o %s %s" % (binobj, asmsrc))
f = os.popen("objdump -j .text -s -z  %s" % (binobj, ))
objdump = f.readlines()
f.close()

regx = re.compile("^ [0-9a-f]{4}")
regxret = ""
for line in objdump:
    if regx.match(line):
        regxret = regxret + "".join(line[:42].split()[1:])
dumphex = []
while regxret:
    dumphex.append(regxret[:2])
    regxret = regxret[2:]
print dumphex
result = ["unsigned char shellcode[] = {",]
for ch in dumphex[:-1]:
    result.append("'\\x%s', " % ch)
result.append("'\\x%s' };" % dumphex[-1:][0])
print "".join(result)
```

**shell command and output:**

```
$ python shellforge2.py hello.c
gcc -march=i386 -O3 -S -fPIC -Winline -finline-functions  -ffreestanding -o hello.s -m32 hello.c

    .text
    .p2align 2,,3
.globl main
    .type   main, @function
main:
    leal    4(%esp), %ecx
    andl    $-16, %esp
    pushl   -4(%ecx)
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    pushl   %edi
    pushl   %esi
    pushl   %ebx
    pushl   %ecx
    subl    $28, %esp
    call    .L3
.L3:
    popl    %ebx
    addl    $_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+[.-.L3], %ebx
    leal    -23(%ebp), %edi
    leal    C.0.751@GOTOFF(%ebx), %esi
    movl    $7, %ecx
    rep movsb
    pushl   $7
    leal    -23(%ebp), %eax
    pushl   %eax
    pushl   $1
    call    write@PLT
    movl    $0, (%esp)
    call    exit@PLT
    addl    $16, %esp
    leal    -16(%ebp), %esp
    popl    %ecx
    popl    %ebx
    popl    %esi
    popl    %edi
    leave
    leal    -4(%ecx), %esp
    ret
    .size   main, .-main
    .section    .rodata
    .type   C.0.751, @object
    .size   C.0.751, 7
C.0.751:
    .byte   72
    .byte   101
    .byte   108
    .byte   108
    .byte   111
    .byte   10
    .byte   0
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 4.3.3-5ubuntu4) 4.3.3"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
['8d', '4c', '24', '04', '83', 'e4', 'f0', 'ff', '71', 'fc', '55', '89', 'e5', '57', '56', '53', '51', '83', 'ec', '1c', 'e8', '00', '00', '00', '00', '5b', '81', 'c3', '03', '00', '00', '00', '8d', '7d', 'e9', '8d', 'b3', '00', '00', '00', '00', 'b9', '07', '00', '00', '00', 'f3', 'a4', '6a', '07', '8d', '45', 'e9', '50', '6a', '01', 'e8', 'fc', 'ff', 'ff', 'ff', 'c7', '04', '24', '00', '00', '00', '00', 'e8', 'fc', 'ff', 'ff', 'ff', '83', 'c4', '10', '8d', '65', 'f0', '59', '5b', '5e', '5f', 'c9', '8d', '61', 'fc', 'c3']
unsigned char shellcode[] = {'\x8d', '\x4c', '\x24', '\x04', '\x83', '\xe4', '\xf0', '\xff', '\x71', '\xfc', '\x55', '\x89', '\xe5', '\x57', '\x56', '\x53', '\x51', '\x83', '\xec', '\x1c', '\xe8', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x5b', '\x81', '\xc3', '\x03', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x8d', '\x7d', '\xe9', '\x8d', '\xb3', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\xb9', '\x07', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\xf3', '\xa4', '\x6a', '\x07', '\x8d', '\x45', '\xe9', '\x50', '\x6a', '\x01', '\xe8', '\xfc', '\xff', '\xff', '\xff', '\xc7', '\x04', '\x24', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\xe8', '\xfc', '\xff', '\xff', '\xff', '\x83', '\xc4', '\x10', '\x8d', '\x65', '\xf0', '\x59', '\x5b', '\x5e', '\x5f', '\xc9', '\x8d', '\x61', '\xfc', '\xc3' };
```

**testshell.c**

```
int main(void) {
    unsigned char shellcode[] = {'\x8d', '\x4c', '\x24', '\x04', '\x83', '\xe4', '\xf0', '\xff', '\x71', '\xfc', '\x55', '\x89', '\xe5', '\x57', '\x56', '\x53', '\x51', '\x83', '\xec', '\x1c', '\xe8', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x5b', '\x81', '\xc3', '\x03', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x8d', '\x7d', '\xe9', '\x8d', '\xb3', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\xb9', '\x07', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\xf3', '\xa4', '\x6a', '\x07', '\x8d', '\x45', '\xe9', '\x50', '\x6a', '\x01', '\xe8', '\xfc', '\xff', '\xff', '\xff', '\xc7', '\x04', '\x24', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\xe8', '\xfc', '\xff', '\xff', '\xff', '\x83', '\xc4', '\x10', '\x8d', '\x65', '\xf0', '\x59', '\x5b', '\x5e', '\x5f', '\xc9', '\x8d', '\x61', '\xfc', '\xc3' };
    int (*_main)(void) = (int (*)(void))shellcode;
    _main();
    return 0;
}
```

`hello.c` is converted from C source into an array of instructions with `shellforge2.py`, which are pasted into `testshell.c`. `testshell.c` is compiled and executed.

```
$ ./testshell
Illegal instruction
```

I hope I made this question clear.

Comment: You really should provide an example of whatever you are talking about. And describe what is the problem with it.

Comment: Firstly, you normally use an assembler to create shellcode, not a compiler. Second, you won't be able to execute shellcode by overwriting the stack in any modern OS, since they have protection against executing memory that is writeable. Read up on ROP (Return Oriented Programming: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return-oriented_programming), which is the modern way to do this.

Comment: @Matthew I have been using assemblers and compilers to create the object files. So basically my question is "off topic" because no correct answer can be given?

Comment: @MotokoKusanagi There is an answer - your question was just too general and poorly worded. The answer is you need to allocate memory using `mmap(2)` (on Linux) and mark the page as `PROT_EXEC | PROT_WRITE` to be able to write and "jump into" it to execute the instructions. This isn't really "exploitation" though, you're just overriding the default behavior.

Comment: Voted to reopen, but it is still lacking information. It's too general. Give an example that *should* work and describe what is the actual outcome.

Comment: @EugeneSh. is that better?

Comment: Yes it is. But I've casted my vote already :)

Comment: BTW, are you aware that you can initialize a char array with a string literal?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes I am aware of that. `hello.c` is that way because a string would not be put on the stack the same way.

Comment: @MotokoKusanagi I recommend you just delete this and do more research. I converted the shellcode in your example .c back into assembly instructions (see here: http://pastie.org/10244014 ) and that would never even run on its own. Don't use "objdump" to craft weird shellcode, actually learn assembly and use nasm or an assembler that can create flat object files. You're *not* going to be able to run shellcode by overwriting the stack on any modern OS, period. If you want a quick fix, just declare your shellcode as `const static unsigned char` as it keeps it read-only, but it will still segfault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with creating shellcode from C programs is not that you cannot control the assembly generated, nor something related with the code generation.
The problem with creating shellcode from C programs is *symbols resolution* or *relocation*, call it whatever you like.

You approach, for what I have understand, is right, you are just using the wrong code or in a different view, you want too much.
I'm not going to explain how the loading of an image works but briefly when you use a function like `write` the assembly generated is a `call ADDRESS` instruction but the address is not compiled yet, it is just a relative offset that will be resolved by the loader at run time with the help of the structures found on the image (see PE, ELF).
Your shell code don't get loaded by the OS (it is a program inside a program) and so its symbols are not resolved. Look at this:

[image: Unresolved symbol]

This is the call to the `write` function in your hello.c as it is executed by stepping with GDB. Note that the call is at `28cbfch` and that the callee should be at `28cbfd`,i.e. just a byte after the start of the instruction. This is not possible as the instruction itself takes 5 bytes, this means that the call to `write` is coded as `call -4`, i.e. a relative address ***not yet resolved by the loader***.

You will learn in your course that shell code usually use system calls directly in Linux with `int 80h` on IA32 platform. If you substitute the call to `write` with a system call invocation your shell code *should* (may be other issues, don't trust me) work.

Fun fact: I was expecting the stack to not be executable (look for NX bit for more info) by default but in cygwin it was indeed. You can use `--execstack` to be sure, for ELF file, that the stack is executable.